# Is there way to send the reports generated by magento (under reports) to a mail?

Tags: email, reports

I need to setup a cron job to send the reports generated by magento to a particular mail. Is there way to configure this ?

Comment: Natively, no. But you could create a custom module to generate and email this report. What format should the report be in html, csv, etc?

Comment: HTML will be nice.